# Images from src/assets/img folder are not displayed in the Ionic View

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

Images from `src/assets/img` folder are not displaying in the Ionic View application on iOS using declaration:
`<img src="assets/img/logo.svg" class="logo"/>`

But, at the same time, locally everything displaying correctly using: `ionic serve` command.

For android everything works fine.
Please, advice, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="../assets/img/logo.svg" class="logo"/>` ?

Comment: As far as I know such approach isn't recommended. For example in conference app: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app `../` isn't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug in the Ionic View 2.0.1 version.
In 2.0.2 version this issue is fixed.

From v2.0.2 release notes:
`Fixed an issue with SVG images not displaying properly`